# Delete jsonb keys when not present in a definition table

Tags: postgresql

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYghNDHwSXVKZ6uMredofZ/0
- Postgresql 10

I have a `jsonb` field in one table (target) and the definition of "allowed" keys for that json field in another (attributes):

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE target (custom JSONB);

INSERT INTO attributes VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
INSERT INTO target VALUES ('{"a": "sth", "b": "sth"}'), ('{"c": "sth"}'), ('{"a": "sth", "d": "sth"}');
```

So in this simplified example the allowed keys are `a,b and c`.

I now have to write a migration which deletes keys and values from the `target` table, which have no valid definition. In this case this would be the key `d`.

With this knowledge I could delete `d`:

`UPDATE target SET custom = custom - 'd';`

But - How can I do this by comparing the two tables and delete all keys from `target.custom` with no key definition in `attributes.name` present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first aggregate all keys that should be deleted for each row in the target table. I am assuming you have some primary key column in that table (`id` in my following example).

This query:

```
select id, array_agg(ky)
from target
   cross join jsonb_each_text(custom) as c(ky,v)
where c.ky not in (select name from attributes)
group by id;
```

collects all keys in an array for each id that should be deleted. This can now be used as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update target 
  set custom = custom - x.keys
from (
  select id, array_agg(ky) as keys
  from target
     cross join jsonb_each_text(custom) as c(ky,v)
     where c.ky not in (select name from attributes)
  group by id
) x
where target.id = x.id;
```

Online example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i7VCtjtJVErLwbS88iww7Q/0

Comment: This is working, thanks! Your example is the same as mine (copy+paste error maybe). I created a new one with the id: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYghNDHwSXVKZ6uMredofZ/1